# reusable components with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, frameworks

Very new to bootstrap and it seems so cool, but as I look around at various templates, I feel I am missing the "template" nature of the code.

How does one build on the sample templates to have, for example, a master index page and reusable components (tabs, sidebars, menus, headers, footers) available to all "rendered" pages?  It does not seem efficient to recode sidebar menus into every page but that's what the samples seem to show.

Perhaps there is a way to have a special div where the variable content can be loaded?

Or, perhaps there is a higher level framework I should be looking at and bootstrap is not the answer for what I need?

Comment: Bootstrap in itself will not do this. Two options to achieve this are: 1. Server-side includes for more templates pieces - like nav, footers, sidebars etc. 2. CMS like Wordpress using a Bootstrap theme.

Comment: Just a third option to add to the list @moodyjive made: you can use an number of javascript templating engines or MV* frameworks like handlebars or AngularJS.  For Angular, there is the UI Bootstrap project that includes all of the javascript plugins rewritten in pure AngularJS http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Very cool @jme11. I have been looking for a way to get into Angular and this might be it!